# FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have a perfectly working setup of FPFD on my localhost(windows) it generates the pdf files alright. However, when i uploaded to the production environment(Linux), it throws this silly error.

I have been trying to trouble shoot for the past 2hrs now. the error does not give  any pointers as to where the stream is suddenly ending. Have posted on their forum but that place looks dead to me.

Please who has used or encountered this error before?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours and days or researching, I found that a png image I was trying to use was not uploaded successfully....it was partially uploaded....I minified the image and reuploaded, and the error disappeared.

Comment: May I ask how you can 'minify an image'?

Comment: @F3L1X79 if you use windows platform, try fileminimizer.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because of the image is not completely uploaded to the particular folder you are storing . Example-> creating an image but that image is not complete then it will give this error . so in this case first check that image is there or not and then put the static url to the pdf->image('static url which you can see in you web browser',0,0,-72) and the check it or else use any web image url to check it .
And when your have space or dot in you url that you are creating after uploading  Example-> https://adc.com/ xyz .png  it will also create the same problem .